# Froala Editor - Don't Minify (condense/squish) My Code

Tags: minify, froala

Is there a setting in Froala to stop it from squishing the values entered while in code view mode? We need to maintain the HTML and when it gets minified it is a nightmare to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I was able to solve it by following this link:

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#code-beautifier

By adding the code beautifier options (by including the code_beautifier.min.js file in your build), the line breaks and tabs are preserved.